# Wordpress <!--more--> adding a <br> to my anchor for Read More

Tags: read-more, html-editor

When creating a post within my wordpress site (using the editor) I want to add the  short code, or even use the link at the top of the editor to do so.

The end result is (it does create the excerpt and add the "Read more" link) but that link is broken and the editor has seemingly inserted a 
 tag within my anchor breaking the link.

`<a href="http://www.seekersolutions.com&lt;br /&gt;
/a-test-post/" class="more-link">Read more »</a>`

Anyone have an idea as to why this would be happening?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a line break in your URL would you? Does this happen with a default theme (Twenty Twelve) with all of your plugins disabled?

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I had a look at the permalink structure and it turns out there is a space right after the end of my url.  I have checked my database there is no space appended on any of the columns in the wp_options table.   Any ideas as to where this could be coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the way that `wpautop` works, I would expect that if you had a newline, or or maybe a space in your URL. I can't seem to get a space or newline to save from the admin interface, but it is trivial to insert by [editing the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants into `wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Blog_address_.28URL.29)... but that causes every page to 404 or worse.

There must be something happening when the link is generated-- possibly something hooked to `excerpt_more` or `the_content_more_link`. It is also possible that your theme is parsing the more link itself and bypassing the normal channels.

Without more information, that is all I have.

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Comment: In addition to this, in the WP_OPTIONS table, even though I cleared any white space in the table the interface was no removing the <br> UNTIL I changed the URL completely.  Once I did that the space was removed and I was able to correctly add my normal URL back to the database without the space.